# How to take derivative of log loss function in gradient descent?

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, python

I know the gradient descent about $z=wx+b$. But how to implement the derivative values of $w$ and $b$ in Python? I see some example like

```
derivative_weight = (np.dot(x_train, ((y_head-y_train).T))) / x_train.shape[1]  
derivative_bias = np.sum(y_head-y_train) / x_train.shape[1]
```

In mathematics is

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial w}=\frac{1}{m}x(y_{head}-y)^T$
$\frac{\partial J}{\partial b}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{head}-y)$

How to get it? How are those formulas derived? Please feel free to help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be worth editing a formula for $J$ into the question as well.

Comment: You may want to check http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html